# VSCode C++ extension auto-complete is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am running vscode with the c/c++ extension by Microsoft.

I have configured the extensions c_cpp_properties.json correctly, so all my includes are working.

I can jump to definition of any symbols in the project correctly.

Yet the auto-completion is not working / really horrible.

When I start typing a variable name, it just shows my an ordered list of literally every symbol in the entire project.

In addition, why I have a variable class instance and I type '.', and I expect autocomplete to complete the members of that particular class, again, it just shows me the entire list of all the symbols of the project.

Is something misconfigured, or is this bug/unimplemented behaviour?

thanks.

Comment: This seems like a question more relevant for Microsoft Support than Stackoverflow...

Comment: Incorrect. Vscode project directs to stackoverflow for questions.

Comment: So they are outsourcing their product support to SO. Hmm, I don't know how I feel about that..

Comment: Its an open source project, not really a "product".

Comment: Go to the Github page of the package. Also try reinstalling it.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm seeing the exact same behaviour ~2 years later...